# How to iterate over all combinations of nested objects?

Tags: scala

I have the following problem which I'm not sure how to model elegantly:

Say I have the following classes:

```
class A(v: String)
class B(v: String, as: Seq[A])
class C(v: String, bs: Seq[B])
```

Given an instance of `C` I want to produce a value for each combination of `C` x `B` x `A`. I want to produce a value even if the `C` instance doesn't have any `B`s or if the `B` instance doesn't have any `A`s.

For simplicity let's say the value I want to produce is a string of the form `c.v - b.v - a.v`.

In other words - I'm looking for a way to implement the following method:

```
def produce(c: C): List[String] = ???
```

Such that:

```
val c1 = new C(v = "c1", bs = Seq.empty)
produce(c1) // List("c1 - - ")

val c2 = new C(
  v = "c1", 
  bs = Seq(new B(v = "b1", as = Seq.empty), new B(v = "b2", as = Seq.empty))
)

produce(c2) // List("c1 - b1 - ", "c1 - b2 - ")


val c3 = new C(
  v = "c1"
  bs = Seq(
    new B(v = "b1", as = Seq(new A("a1"), new A("a2)))
    new B(v = "b2", as = Seq(new A("a3"), new A("a4))),
  )
)

produce(c3) // List("c1 - b1 - a1",
            //      "c1 - b1 - a2",
            //      "c1 - b2 - a3",
            //      "c1 - b2 - a4")
```

I tried achiving this using a for comprehension but since `flatMap`ing over an empty `Seq` doesn't yield a value I had to turn empty `Seq`s into non empty ones. The code turned out complex and long.

My question is what is the best way to do this? Is there some data structure which can help make this simpler?

Thanks.

Comment: You could try to pattern match over the as/bs sequences and implement the corresponding behaviour for empty/non-empty cases.

Comment: @jarandaf ok I think I understand what you mean, but I think that will result in a number of nested for-comprehension (or simply `flatMap`s) and pattern mathings. That will work, but I'm looking for something more elegane \ idiomatic (especially if you have more the three nestings).

Comment: the output `"c1 - - "` assumes that `C` knows how many nested levels are below it.  Is that a known?

Comment: @maasg yes, number of nested levels is know.

Comment: the answer from @jwvh is good. Any reason why you don't accept it?  Do you want to see anything differently?

Comment: @maasg It is good, I agree and I've accepted it but I'd actually want to see more solutions for this - maybe something more generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this gets at what you're after. I turned your classes into case classes to make the pattern matching easier.

```
sealed abstract class VSet
case class A(v: String) extends VSet
case class B(v: String, as: Seq[A]) extends VSet
case class C(v: String, bs: Seq[B]) extends VSet

def produce(vset: VSet, prefix: String = ""): Seq[String] = vset match {
  case C(v, bs) => if (bs.isEmpty) Seq(s"$v -")
                   else bs.flatMap(produce(_, s"$v => "))
  case B(v, as) => if (as.isEmpty) Seq(s"$prefix$v -")
                   else as.flatMap(produce(_, s"$prefix$v => "))
  case A(v) => Seq(s"$prefix$v")
}
```